# Python3 how to create a list of partial products

Tags: list, for-loop, optimization

I have a very long list (of big numbers),  let's say for example:

`a=[4,6,7,2,8,2]`

I need to get this output:

`b=[4,24,168,336,2688,5376]`

where each `b[i]=a[0]*a[1]...*a[i]`

I'm trying to do this recursively in this way:

```
b=[4] + [ a[i-1]*a[i] for i in range(1,6)]
```

but the (wrong) result is: `[4, 24, 42, 14, 16, 16]`

I don't want to compute all the products each time, I need a efficient way (if possible), because the list is very long

At the moment this works for me:

```
b=[0]*6
b[0]=4

for i in range(1,6): b[i]=a[i]*b[i-1]
```

but it's too slow. Any ideas? Is it possible to avoid "for" or to speedup it in other way?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the product step-by-step since every next calculation heavily depends on the previous one.

What I mean is:
1) Compute the product for the first `i - 1` numbers
2) The i-th product will be equal to `a[i]` * product of the last `i - 1` numbers

This method is called [*dynamic programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)

> Dynamic programming (also known as dynamic optimization) is a method for solving a complex problem by breaking it down into a collection of simpler subproblems, solving each of those subproblems just once, and storing their solutions

This is the implementation:

```
a = [4, 6, 7, 2, 8, 2]
b = []

product_so_far = 1

for i in range(len(a)):
    product_so_far *= a[i]
    b.append(product_so_far)

print(b)
```

This algorithm works in linear time (`O(n)`), which is the most efficient complexity you'll get for such a task

If you want a little optimization, you could generate the `b` list to the predefined length (`b = [0] * len(a)`) and, instead of appending, you would do this in a loop:
`b[i] = product_so_far`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Ok for the complexity, but what about the python implementation? There is a better way (map or such things) that could speedup computations?

Comment: @arulbero no, this is probably the fastest you can get. Maps in Python work best with built-ins, because they're partly implemented in C and other low-level languages. If you really want **the best** performance, you could write this loop in Cython (mix of Python and C), but that would be overkill - this algorithm is good enough

Comment: @arulbero but check out the edit, there is actually a way to get a little gain

Comment: @arulbero technically your code works a little bit slower, since you access an element of a list each time. It would be better to store it in a variable, like in my implementation

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `accumulate` function and the `mul` operator allow you to do exactly this, without any unnecessary multiplications:

```py
from itertools import accumulate
from operator import mul

a = [4, 6, 7, 2, 8, 2]
print(list(accumulate(a, mul)))
```

```py
[4, 24, 168, 336, 2688, 5376]
```